# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'. When trying to scrape using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm trying to scrape the table from this website https://vcx-forum.org/score, when I tried to scrape using beautiful soup it shows error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`

Below are my code snippet

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://vcx-forum.org/score")

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

key = {} 
data = []

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for tag in soup.find_all('div', class_="vcx-ranking__body js-vcx-ranking-body"):
    for span in tag.find_all('div', class_="t-row"):
        for row in span:
            model = row.find("div", class_="t_cell colCamera").find("a").text
            rating = row.find("div", class_="t_cell colScore colVCX active").find("span", 
                                                                                            class_="score_numeric").text
            image_quality = row.find("div", class_="t_cell colScore colImageQuality").text
            sunny = row.find("div", class_="t_cell colScore colBright").text
            indoor = row.find("div", class_="t_cell colScore colMid").text
            night = row.find("div", class_="t_cell colScore colImageLow").text
            flash = row.find("div", class_="t_cell colScore colFlash").text
            zoom = row.find("div", class_="t_cell colScore colZoom").text
            perform = row.find("div", class_="t_cell colScore colHandling").text

            key = {'model':[model],
                    'image_quality':[image_quality],
                    'sunny':[sunny],
                    'indoor':[indoor],
                    'night':[night],
                    'flash':[flash],
                    'zoom':[zoom],
                    'perform':[perform]
                  }

df = pd.DataFrame(key, columns = ['model', 'rating','image_quality', 'sunny',
                                     'indoor', 'night', 'flash', 'zoom', 'perform'])
```

I've tried print(span.text) after the for span line, but it only display everything inside the div class of t-row and i want all to be separated nicely into column names

EDITED :

```
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-f1da6a7e61dd> in <module>
     16     for span in tag.find_all('div', class_="t-row"):
     17         for row in span:
---> 18             model = row.find("div", class_="t_cell colCamera").find("a").text
     19             rating = row.find("div", class_="t_cell colScore colVCX active").find("span", 
     20                                                                                             class_="score_numeric").text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: Post the traceback. Don't expect us to search for the failing line. The error means that a variable that you think holds an element is None. When you locate the failing line, see where that variable came from.

Comment: Posted the traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes of your code.It is working fine now.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://vcx-forum.org/score")

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(5)
key = {}
data = []

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for row in soup.find_all('div', class_="t-row")[1:]:

      model = row.select_one('.colCamera>a').text
      rating = row.select_one(".t-cell.colScore.colVCX.active>.score-numeric").text
      image_quality = row.select_one(".colImageQuality").text
      sunny = row.select_one(".colBright").text
      indoor = row.select_one(".colMid").text
      night = row.select_one(".colLow").text
      flash = row.select_one(".colFlash").text
      zoom = row.select_one(".colZoom").text
      perform = row.select_one(".colHandling").text

      key = {'model':[model],
             'rating':[rating],
                    'image_quality':[image_quality],
                    'sunny':[sunny],
                    'indoor':[indoor],
                    'night':[night],
                    'flash':[flash],
                    'zoom':[zoom],
                    'perform':[perform]
                  }
      data.append(key)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['model', 'rating','image_quality', 'sunny',
                                     'indoor', 'night', 'flash', 'zoom', 'perform'])

print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
                             model rating image_quality  ... flash  zoom perform
0                 [Xiaomi Mi 10 Pro]   [73]          [69]  ...  [68]  [71]    [80]
1         [Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra]   [77]          [76]  ...  [74]  [74]    [78]
2               [Samsung Galaxy S20]   [75]          [74]  ...  [74]  [51]    [78]
3               [Huawei Mate 30 Pro]   [77]          [73]  ...  [76]  [63]    [87]
4            [Xiaomi MI note 10 pro]   [75]          [72]  ...  [71]  [78]    [82]
5                     [LG G8S ThinQ]   [77]          [74]  ...  [71]  [42]    [82]
6                     [LG V50 ThinQ]   [76]          [75]  ...  [74]  [42]    [79]
7                      [LG G8 ThinQ]   [77]          [75]  ...  [72]  [43]    [81]
8                   [Huawei Mate 20]   [73]          [71]  ...  [68]  [36]    [76]
9               [Huawei Mate 20 Pro]   [75]          [72]  ...  [62]  [45]    [81]
10                  [Huawei P20 Pro]   [74]          [70]  ...  [67]  [52]    [83]
11                [Oppo Find X2 Pro]   [71]          [69]  ...  [63]  [61]    [73]
12             [Apple iPhone 11 Pro]   [72]          [71]  ...  [73]  [41]    [74]
13                      [Oppo Reno2]   [69]          [67]  ...  [65]  [42]    [75]
14           [Samsung Galaxy Note10]   [71]          [68]  ...  [61]  [44]    [77]
15                     [Xiaomi MI 9]   [70]          [70]  ...  [70]  [48]    [71]
16                  [Huawei P30 Pro]   [72]          [68]  ...  [71]  [51]    [79]
17                      [Huawei P30]   [69]          [68]  ...  [70]  [50]    [71]
18                          [LG V40]   [72]          [71]  ...  [72]  [42]    [74]
19                      [Huawei P20]   [71]          [66]  ...  [65]  [34]    [83]
20                         [HTC U11]   [70]          [65]  ...  [69]  [15]    [82]
21                    [Realme 5 Pro]   [66]          [64]  ...  [65]  [10]    [72]
22                     [Fairphone 3]   [64]          [63]  ...  [72]  [25]    [65]
23                  [Google Pixel 4]   [66]          [68]  ...  [65]  [43]    [63]
24         [Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max]   [68]          [70]  ...  [72]  [31]    [64]
25                   [Oneplus 7 Pro]   [67]          [66]  ...  [62]  [55]    [68]
26                    [Samsung  S10]   [68]          [66]  ...  [62]  [41]    [73]
27           [Samsung Galaxy Note 9]   [66]          [65]  ...  [64]  [42]    [68]
28                  [Google Pixel 3]   [65]          [60]  ...  [63]  [13]    [75]
29                [Red Hydrogen One]   [68]          [63]  ...  [61]  [12]    [78]
..                               ...    ...           ...  ...   ...   ...     ...
85                 [Blackberry Priv]   [52]          [55]  ...  [61]  [10]    [45]
86                 [Apple iPhone SE]   [52]          [51]  ...  [54]   [1]    [54]
87                  [Apple iPhone 7]   [52]          [49]  ...  [50]   [7]    [60]
88              [Vodafone Smart N10]   [49]          [44]  ...  [40]  [-8]    [61]
89               [Vodafone Smart N8]   [48]          [45]  ...  [43]   [9]    [55]
90               [Vodafone Smart N9]   [46]          [42]  ...  [37]   [0]    [56]
91                  [Huawei P Smart]   [49]          [46]  ...  [43]  [15]    [57]
92                 [Huawei P20 Lite]   [50]          [56]  ...  [57]  [16]    [37]
93                  [Sony Xperia Z3]   [46]          [44]  ...  [43]   [4]    [52]
94             [Microsoft Lumia 650]   [47]          [44]  ...  [41]  [13]    [53]
95                           [LG G3]   [48]          [42]  ...  [42]   [0]    [62]
96                 [Huawei GX8 (G8)]   [50]          [45]  ...  [54]   [0]    [63]
97                      [HTC One M8]   [45]          [43]  ...  [45]   [0]    [52]
98                 [Apple iPhone 6S]   [47]          [46]  ...  [56]   [5]    [47]
99             [Apple iPhone 6 Plus]   [49]          [45]  ...  [52]   [0]    [58]
100           [Alcatel (TCT) Idol 3]   [43]          [46]  ...  [40]  [26]    [35]
101                   [Sony M4 Aqua]   [42]          [43]  ...  [45]   [6]    [38]
102  [Motorola Moto G 3. Generation]   [43]          [41]  ...  [36]   [1]    [49]
103                      [Huawei P8]   [43]          [43]  ...  [49]   [0]    [42]
104                 [Huawei P8 lite]   [42]          [42]  ...  [47]  [13]    [40]
105         [Vodafone Smart N9 lite]   [39]          [39]  ...  [37]   [2]    [37]
106         [Vodafone Smart Ultra 7]   [40]          [39]  ...  [48]   [0]    [44]
107         [Vodafone Smart Prime 7]   [38]          [33]  ...  [30]   [0]    [50]
108          [Vodafone Smart Mini 7]   [37]          [20]  ...   [0]   [0]    [77]
109              [Samsung Galaxy J5]   [39]          [40]  ...  [46]   [0]    [37]
110             [Samsung Core prime]   [36]          [34]  ...  [36]   [0]    [41]
111         [Microsoft Lumia 640 XL]   [40]          [39]  ...  [38]   [0]    [41]
112                         [LG G4c]   [40]          [37]  ...  [33]   [0]    [48]
113                 [HTC Desire 626]   [38]          [39]  ...  [30]   [0]    [35]
114                          [LG K4]   [33]          [24]  ...  [15]   [0]    [53]

[115 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: Ahh i didnt thought at first about using css selector to read the class, thank you! It works now